# Setting cursor using style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cursor

```
<Window x:Class="ResizeMove0923.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style  TargetType="Control"  >
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeAll" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Canvas Background="Beige" Name="canvas" >
    <Label Canvas.Left="72" Canvas.Top="23" Height="23" Name="textbox1" Width="75" Content="ttttt"    />
    <TextBox Height="21" Canvas.Left="147" Canvas.Top="23" Width="75" Name="textbox2" Text="&amp;Well" />
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="147" Canvas.Top="60" Height="24" Name="textBox3" Width="128"  />
</Canvas>
```

As a newbie I am having trouble setting the cursor type for all elements in my canvas, using Style. If I give the TargetType as Label or TextBox, it works. But I want the cursor to change for all types of elements that will be added to the canvas. What is wrong with my Style element?

Answer (score 2):

Set it directly on the `Canvas` and also set [`ForceCursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.forcecursor(v=vs.110).aspx) to true, this will prevent child elements from overriding:

```
<Canvas Background="Beige" Name="canvas" Cursor="SizeAll" ForceCursor="True">
   ...
</Canvas>
```

> If I give the TargetType as Label or TextBox, it works.

Implicit styles work only when `TargetType` matches - from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.style.aspx#implicit):

> If you set the style implicitly, the style is applied only to the
>   types that match the TargetType exactly and not to elements derived
>   from the TargetType value. For example, if you create a style
>   implicitly for all the ToggleButton controls in your application, and
>   your application has ToggleButton and CheckBox controls (CheckBox
>   derives from ToggleButton), the "ToggleButton" implicit style is
>   applied only to the ToggleButton controls.

Comment: That makes the cursor SizeAll no matter where the mouse is in the canvas. What I want is that the cursor changes to SizeAll only when mouse is over one of the elements inside the canvas. So for instance, in the above XAML there are 3 elements. I want the SizeAll cursor only when mouse is over one of these 3 elements, and elsewhere in the canvas it should switch back to the normal pointer cursor

Comment: @user2192101 In question you have write, that you want change cursor for all elements, also there is nothing about MouseOver or something else